# Errors installing Pow server on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion

When attempting to install the [Pow](http://pow.cx/) server on my mac, everything appears to be going well. I run `curl get.pow.cx | sh` and receive confirmation that the package was installed correctly. However, when I `cd ~/.pow` and create the necessary symlink: `ln -s /path/to/myapp` I receive the following error: `ln: ./myapp: File exists` Upon navigating to `http://myapp.dev` I receive the standard `Application not found` error

Troubleshooting steps taken:

Uninstalled pow: `curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh`

Removed the pow folder: `rm -Rf ~/.pow`

Removed the link: `rm -Rf ~/.myapp`

Restarted mac

Reinstalled Pow

Still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ln says the file exists, the symlink may already be there?

Once pow is installed, this is what I do:

1. Go to the pow dir: `cd ~/.pow`
2. Create a symlink to my app's directory: `ln -s ~/dev/myapp myapp`

   1. Additionally, the `~/dev/myapp` folder has a "public" directory inside of it. It's required.
3. Browse to `http://myapp.dev`

Maybe be explicit with your symlink name, as I was in #2?

Comment: I went to the pow dir with `cd ~/.pow` and ran `ln -s ~/dev/Users/Anconia/myapp /Users/Anconia/myapp` and received the same error

Comment: You're syntax is wrong. Should be `cd ~/.power` and then `ln -s ~/dev/Users/Anconia/myapp myapp` Your second argument to ln is just the name of the symlink, don't give it a path since you want the symlink to be inside of ~/.pow

Answer (score 0):

Got this running by first uninstalling Pow: `curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh`

Then reinstalling: `curl get.pow.cx | sh`

Going to the Pow directory: `cd ~/.pow`

Issuing the following command: `rm ./myapp`

Recreating the symlink: `ln -s /path/to/maypp`